# Downloading an xml file with JavaScript and save it in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a PhoneGap Application using jQuery Mobile.
I have an xml file located on a server on the internet (accessible via a web server (e.g. http://www.example.com/myXmlFile.xml)). I want to somehow read this xml file and save the content of the file in a variable as a string in Java Script.
How would you do this?

```
var contentOfXmlFile = "";

read Xml file --> Save it in the contentOfXmlFile variable.

alert(contentOfXmlFile);
```

After this the text from the xml file would be shown in the alert window.

Comment: Since you're doing things off of PhoneGap, any AJAX requests will violate cross-domain policies. Have you looked into JSONP requests?

Comment: When you are running from the file:// protocol on mobile devices the cross-domain policy is not applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use AJAX:

```
var myXML = ""
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/myXmlFile.xml", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            myXML = request.responseXML;
        }
    }
}
request.send();
```

The variable myXML will be an XML Document that you can manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with an ajax query something like follwing...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type :"GET",
    url : dataUrl,
    success : function(dataXML){
        //dataXML will have the complete xml..
    },
    error : function(){
        //error handler..
    }
});
```

Where dataUrl is your URL to xml.

Comment: This might violate the cross-domain policy, since PhoneGap runs on `localhost`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: For cross domain, hope we need to use `JSONP`, I haven't tried that anytime though.

Comment: When you are running from the file:// protocol on mobile devices the cross-domain policy is not applied.